# parameter exists using express-validator

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I am using [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-validator) for validation.

I have some parameters which are not mandatory like name.

I want to validate the parameter only if was exists, else no need to validate.

I have got a solution like

```
if(parameter){
   req.assert('name',"Valid name is required!").isName();
}
```

Is there any better solution than this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Latest version of [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-validator) solved this issue

```
req.assert('name',"Valid name is required!").optional().isName();
```

Comment: It should be `.optional()` rather than `.optional`